# Верна ли в этом предложении пунктуация? Как верно?

Tags: пунктуация

"Но понять, что там, внутри, в автобусе, происходит, не так просто - на то это тонировка."

Comment: *на то это тонировка* - что такое "на то это"?  Есть оборот "на то и":  *На то и щука в реке, чтобы карась не дремал.* А вот "на то это" - не понимаю. Понял бы еще (поморщившись) "на то это **и** тонировка". Хотя и тут "это" совершенно лишнее.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне кажется, что нужны только запятые ограничивающие придаточное, потому что можно плавно, без пауз произнести эту часть:

*Но понять, что там внутри в автобусе происходит, не так просто — на то *и* тонировка.*

С другой стороны, если Вы делаете эти паузы, тогда, по-моему, надо оставить как у Вас.

---

*Обновление:*
**Поменял "это" на "и" по подсказке behemothus-а.** А то действительно получается ерунда.

Comment: А как вы вообще, простите, понимаете смысл "на то это"?

Comment: Да, совершенно верно, не вдумался, что это звучит плохо. Конечно, должно быть "на то и"!

Answer (score 0):

Конечно, надо видеть предыдущий текст, но мне кажется, что **уточняющие обстоятельства здесь лишние:**

Но понять, что там внутри автобуса происходит, не так просто, - на то и тонировка.

Вместо тире  (в качестве варианта) можно использовать **запятую и тире** как единый знак, так как присоединительный оборот с причинным значением  относится к сложному предложению. Пауза здесь длиннее, чем при обычном тире, больше соответствует двоеточию.